# How do I use a variable outside the scope? (Error: CS0136)

Tags: c#

I wrote a program that reads a PDF file and then shows some information about it. It works fine.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //some variables
            string plabels = null;
            string text2Search = "IX";
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("file.pdf");
            string[] labels = PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(reader);

            for (int l = 0; l < labels.Length; l++)
            {
                plabels += labels[l] + "\n";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(plabels.IndexOf(text2Search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I also wrote another program that reads a PDF file and makes a copy of it. It also works fine.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            byte[] bytes;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new PdfReader("file.pdf"))
                {
                    using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                    {

                    }
                }
                //grab the bytes before closing things out
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes("output.pdf", bytes);
        }
    }
```

What I cannot do is to combine these two programs into one.

**EDIT**

Thanks to your comments I spotted an error. Now my code compiles fine, but when run it gives `"Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` The error point to line `for(int l = 0; l < labels.Length; l++)`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        byte[] bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new PdfReader("file.pdf"))
            {
                //some variables
                string plabels = null;
                string text2Search = "IX";
                string[] labels = PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(reader);
                for(int l = 0; l < labels.Length; l++)
                    {
                    plabels += labels[l] + "\n";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(plabels.IndexOf(text2Search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                Console.ReadLine();
                using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                {

                }
            }
            //grab the bytes before closing things out
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes("output.pdf", bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a variable outside of the current scope, that's the whole point of scope.  What you *can* do, is define a variable at a higher scope so that it is in-scope in more places.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I changed the code. Now it compiles fine but when run gives an error. For more details please see my updates post.

Comment: The thing is that I use `GetPageLabels()` in my first program and it runs without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

`reader` is already defined in the using statement.  You cannot re-use that variable name inside the using block.  Change the name of one of the `reader` variables or get rid of it.

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("file.pdf"))
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("file.pdf"); //is redundant.
}
```

Comment: When I do that, program compiles fine but when run it gives `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

Comment: I think that is a different problem.  I answered the original question.  Now the answer looks unrelated.  For the NullReferenceException, I think @grant is right in the comments - you need to check if `labels` is null before using it.  Is it possible that `GetPageLabels` returns null if there are no labels?

Comment: Perhaps it does. But my first program works fine and I use the same code and the same PDF file (that has labels) so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

labels is null.  Your `PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(reader);`
 is not returning a value so look in there.  No code is posted so I can't give you a clearer answer.

Comment: What do you mean by `no code is posted`? You are right as to the null - I debugged the code in VS.

Comment: I mean I don't see the GetPageLabels method to help you understand what it's null.